# reset mysql root password faild. mysql_safe not found

Tags: mysql, passwords, reset, mariadb, percona

I'm using Archlinux with Mariadb sql server.
I tried to reset root password of mysql using [this method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html) which had no problem before.
But now, when I type `mysqld_safe --init-file=/home/me/mysql-init &` in terminal, It says:

```
bash: mysql_safe: command not found
```

What can I do? To fix this? Is there any alternative way to do it?

---

ps:
I installed `percona-server` instead of `mariadb` and I had password problem, After switching to `mariadb` again, problem was still there waiting for me.

Comment: Find what path `mysqld_safe` is located in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no **mysql_safe** script. Try mysqld_safe instead.